# simulate differente Src IP (spoofing) for testing geoip filtering

Tags: iptables, ip, tcp

I would like to simulate different ips for testing traffic filtering according to the ip origin.

I did some tests using iptables and 2 containers simulating node1 and node2 using a bridge network.

- node1 is the one spoofing its source address and send requests to node2
- node2 is just the receiving end, where we intend to check the origin of the ip

I tried first with ICMP which was easy :

```bash
# node1 : target icmp protocol and change the src @
node1> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p icmp -j SNAT --to-source 0.0.1.45

# node2 : redirect traffic targeted to 192.168.1.66 to 
node2> declare node1="$(dig +short node1)"
node2> iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p icmp -d 0.0.1.45 -j DNAT --to-source $node1
```

TCP ip spoofing turned out not to be so simple :
I tried to simulate the ip 223.253.0.5 by SNATing the request and using DNAT rules to send back the traffic to the real host.
tcpdump on node2 showed me the request is well received but the packet must be dropped at some point before it reaches userland.

```bash
# node1 : 
node1> declare node2="$( dig +short node2 )"
node1> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d "$node2" --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 223.253.0.5
node1> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d "$node2" --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 223.253.0.5


# node2 : where we check the origin of the ip
node2> declare node1="$(dig +short node1)"
node2> iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 223.253.0.5 -j DNAT --to-destination $node  # to send back traffic to the spoofer
```

To simulate a request I used curl

```bash
# on the client's side
node1> curl -vvv --insecure -Ls http://$node2:80

# or using socat
  # the client 
node1> socat - TCP:node2:80 
  # the server
node2> socat - TCP-LISTEN:80,fork,bind=172.16.2.6
```

I'm really curious to know why I can't have it working using TCP.

Comment: Not sure how you came to the conclusion that "it works for ICMP", but NAT doesn't really work like that, at least not in Linux. The DNAT and SNAT rule will only be matched for "NEW" traffics in a "connection", i.e., the initiating traffics, so the DNAT rule will not affect traffics that are replying to the SNAT'd traffic. (All non-NEW traffics will be NAT'd according to their corresponding conntrack entry, which is why the SNAT will keep going.) Same story if the DNAT host is initiating the connection. (The SNAT rule will not be in effect to the corresponding replies and so on.)

Comment: Btw, it might make more / some sense to use `set ip saddr` / `set ip daddr` in nftables at appropriate stages for your goal.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the pointers. Needs to buff up then on conntrack and nftables then. I said it worked with icmp because my ping on node1 received its answers and seems pretty ok with it. I guess it should be the same with udp.